# Как правильно проходить по каждому элементу массива?

Tags: javascript

Автор книги "Выразительный JavaScript" для прохождения по каждому элементу массива использует всегда конструкцию `for( var i = 0; i < array.length; i += 1 ) { /* code */}`

Но существует вариант forEach, но вызов функций обходится дороже JavaScript-у, чем вызов циклов.

Также для прохождения по каждому свойству объекта можно использовать `for ( prop in object ) { /* code */ }`, а так, как массив — это подвид объекта, то такую конструкцию можно использовать и для массивов, обращаясь к каждому элементу object[prop].

Есть ли причины почему стоит использовать именно первый вариант, вместо второго и особенно третьего?

Comment: Вот неплохое объяснение https://davidtang.io/2016/07/30/javascript-for-loop-vs-array-foreach.html . Но это дело привычки

Comment: Вы ещё про `for (... of ...)` забыли)

Comment: Само название книги говорит само за себя *Выразительный JavaScript*. Дело в том, что для многих конструкция `for( var i = 0; i < array.length; i += 1 ) { /* code */}` гораздо привычнее, чем `forEach`, потому как появилась задолго до остальных способов. Хотя тенденция со временем может и поменяться.

Comment: Просто, автор упоминал, что любит краткость в записях, поэтому, когда можно не использует фигурные скобки для циклов и условий, но этот вариант прохода по массиву далеко не самый короткий.